# Torsion As The Rate Of Change Of An Angle

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

Just as we define the signed curvature of a plane curve as the rate of change of the angle through which a constant vector must be rotated to bring it into coincidence with the tangent vector, is it possible to define the torsion of a space curve similarily?

Comment: Not really. Torsion gives you the rate at which the osculating plane is turning. Then you have to interpret the sign.